# How to print HTTP header with Winpcap in C

Tags: c, winpcap

I've tried to code a sniffer (TCP only) and I want to print out the HTTP Headers. The headers are saved as a txt log file. But the output is not as expected. 
[output_screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTcLq.png)

Here is the C code:

```
void Print_http_request(u_char *Buffer, int Size) { //Buffer: The beginning of the captured packets.
    int iphdrlen = 0; //IP header length
    int tcphdrlen = 0; //TCP header length
    iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)(Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR)); //allocate IP header
    iphdrlen = iphdr->ip_header_len * 4; //4(bytes)* ip_header_len(words)
    tcpheader = (TCP_HDR*)(Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(ETHER_HDR));//allocate TCP header
    tcphdrlen = tcpheader->data_offset * 4;

    data = (Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR) + iphdrlen + tcphdrlen); //Allocate TCP data = the beginning of HTTP header.
    data_size = iphdr->ip_total_length * 4 - iphdrlen - tcphdrlen; //TCP data size (such as HTTP header, HTTP body)

    //fprintf(logfile, "HTTP HEADER\n");
    fprintf(logfile, "\n===========================\n");
    int _i = 0;
    while (_i < data_size) {
        fprintf(logfile, "%c", data[_i++]);
    }
    fprintf(logfile, "\n===========================\n");
}
```

I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: What went wrong? The gibberish characters in the output, the errors about missing DLLs, or something else? Please edit your question to precisely state the problem and include all relevant information as text, not an image.

Comment: ...anyway, whether or not your compiler is doing what you expect right now, if `TCP_HDR` is not a `char` type or a `struct` containing only `char`s, then reinterpreting a series of `char`s as a `TCP_HDR` is undefined behaviour per the Standard - meaning anything can happen. That may not be the problem right now, but it may create one later. You should properly allocate a `TCP_HDR` and then `memcpy` to it, then read that. This is the portable way to 'reinterpret' a series of bytes as another object - and in many cases gets optimised to a cost-free cast anyway if the compiler/platform support it

Comment: @underscore_d I've edited my question.

Comment: @underscore_d my TCP_HDR is fine. I just want to print the http header.

Comment: @underscore_d I may not clearly understand your point. Can you explain more?

Comment: Search for _strict aliasing_, which renders undefined any attempts to access objects through incompatible pointer types. An allowance is made to cast any pointer _to_ a `char *`, but not the other way around. So, technically, although it may seem to work, if `TCP_HDR` is incompatible with `char` per the normal rules, the code produces undefined behaviour. This may or may not be the problem right now, but on a long enough timeline, it will be a problem. In contrast, declaring a proper `TCP_HDR` and `memcpy`ing to it is well-defined as it avoids aliasing, ensures sufficient alignment, and so on.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks you for your help. I'll do it for my TCP_HDR.
But, why I can't print HTTP header as character like above? Is it related to the TCP_HDR? Because I allocate the the pointer [data] independently to TCP_HDR.